# handlebars template to a button

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js

I am trying to understand handlebars a bit more. I have a simpe image that I want to append a function using handlebars- but not quite understanding how to connect it. It works when I click the text click here, but also want it to work, when the img is clicked.

```js
$(function() {
    
    Handlebars.registerHelper('stringifyFunc', function(fn) {
         return new Handlebars.SafeString("(" + 
                    fn.toString().replace(/\"/g,"'") + ")()");
    });
    
    var source = $('#profile').html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    
    var data = {
      "text": "click here",
       img: "#profile",
      "func": function(){
        alert("Clicked");
      }
    };
    var res = template(data);
    
    $('body').append(template(data));
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cloud.github.com/downloads/wycats/handlebars.js/handlebars-1.0.rc.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/template" id="profile">
          <span onclick="{{stringifyFunc func}}">{{text}}</span>       
        </script>
 <div class='selectorField draggableField'>
           <label class="control-label" style="vertical-align:top">Profile:</label>
     <div class='selectorField draggableField'>
   <img id="profile" src=".png"/>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is really, *really* convoluted. There is no reason to try to inject executable JavaScript into `onclick` properties in your template. Whatever it is you're trying to accomplish can be achieved with unobtrusive event handlers bound on the containing element.

Comment: I am trying to create an application where non coders can use. its just drag/drop element to screen with the functionality already bound